# How to quit game in cocos2d-x with jsb

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x

In my Game , I call the following code to quit game ,but it appeared a black screen.

javascript:

```
 cc.Director.getInstance().end();
```

Answer (score 1):

The black screen is the 'normal' behavior for the end() function. In fact it releases the director's resources (sprite/texture caches, opengl view...) and the running scene and stop the main loop. Have a look at CCDirector::end() and CCDirector::purgeDirector() in the cpp sources.

To actually quit the app/game you'll have to call 'exit()' which is a standard C library function. I don't know if 'exit' is already binded to Javascript (I guess not) but I you bind it your self if your really need it.

Note that not all platforms allow the user to actually quit the app and your game might be rejected if submitted with that feature.

Laurent